# Create page containing only text

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

I need to create a page like this:

https://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/P34576.fasta

in joomla.

How do I remove everything from my template and show only raw text?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Joomla component: Output without html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10739611/joomla-component-output-without-html)

Comment: @kbr85 you don't yet have a [joomla.se] Stack Exchange account yet.  It will come in handy if you have Joomla support questions in the future.  That site is a good place to research your issues as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `?tmpl=component` suffix to the url e.g. https://website.com/index.php?tmpl=component so that only the component is displayed but this will still contain HTML code rather than plain text.

Comment: How do I make Joomla to add ?tmpl=component to the url?

Comment: You could create a menu option using Menu Item Type = URL with the specific URL or add a link in an article. You could also create a simple URL and redirect it to the required URL using the Redirect Component. It's difficult to know what's required with the limited information provided.